# iOS setValue withCompletionBlock not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been running into some completionBlocks not being called on iOS (simulator and device) when setting values, for example:

```
- (void)addShortUserPlaylistUrl:(NSString *)playlistId
                   playlistName:(NSString *)playlistName 
                userDisplayName:(NSString *)userDisplayName 
                completionBlock:(ObjectBlock)completionBlock 

{ 

    FIRDatabaseReference *newUserPlaylistUrlRef = [[_root child:KPLRUserPlaylistUrlRef] childByAutoId]; 

    if (newUserPlaylistUrlRef != nil) { 

        NSString *key = [newUserPlaylistUrlRef key]; 
        NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"playlistId" : playlistId, 
                                @"playlistName" : playlistName, 
                                @"userDisplayName" : userDisplayName 
                                }; 

        [newUserPlaylistUrlRef setValue:dict withCompletionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error, FIRDatabaseReference * _Nonnull ref) { 

            //completion block not called, this code is never reached...
            completionBlock(key, error);  

        }]; 
    } 
}
```

- I am connected to the internet
- The data is written to the server:

screenshot of the Firebase console right after the `setValue`:

[image: screenshot of the firebase console right after the setValue]

Here is the firebase log in XCode after the setValue:

```
2016-10-07 18:53:54.775 Metalplay PREPROD[1157:833315] [FirebaseDatabase] Setting: /plr-playlist-url/plr-user-playlist-url/-KTVGurwKGAvnSglB88N with {
    playlistId = "-KTK7289xor0Fba6Y3SW";
    playlistName = TITO;
    userDisplayName = eussam3;
} pri: <null>
2016-10-07 18:53:54.777 Metalplay PREPROD[1157:833315] [FirebaseDatabase] Was connected, and added as index: 4
2016-10-07 18:53:54.779 Metalplay PREPROD[1157:833315] [FirebaseDatabase] Sending: {
    d =     {
        a = p;
        b =         {
            d =             {
                playlistId = "-KTK7289xor0Fba6Y3SW";
                playlistName = TITO;
                userDisplayName = eussam3;
            };
            p = "/plr-playlist-url/plr-user-playlist-url/-KTVGurwKGAvnSglB88N";
        };
        r = 15;
    };
    t = d;
}
2016-10-07 18:53:54.780 Metalplay PREPROD[1157:833315] [FirebaseDatabase] (wsc:3) resetting keepalive, to 2016-10-07 17:54:39 +0000 ; old: 2016-10-07 17:54:22 +0000
2016-10-07 18:53:55.011 Metalplay PREPROD[1157:833347] [FirebaseDatabase] (wsc:3) handleNewFrameCount: 1
2016-10-07 18:53:55.012 Metalplay PREPROD[1157:833347] [FirebaseDatabase] (wsc:3) handleIncomingFrame sending complete frame: 0
2016-10-07 18:53:55.012 Metalplay PREPROD[1157:833347] [FirebaseDatabase] Got data message: {
    b =     {
        d = "";
        s = ok;
    };
    r = 15;
}
2016-10-07 18:54:39.781 Metalplay PREPROD[1157:832417] [FirebaseDatabase] (wsc:3) nop
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

UPDATE:

Here is a simplier version of the method, which only displays a log on the console when the completion block is executed:

```
- (void)addShortUserPlaylistUrl:(NSString *)playlistId
                   playlistName:(NSString *)playlistName
                userDisplayName:(NSString *)userDisplayName
                completionBlock:(ObjectBlock)completionBlock
{
    FIRDatabaseReference *newUserPlaylistUrlRef = [[_root child:KPLRUserPlaylistUrlRef] childByAutoId];
    if (newUserPlaylistUrlRef != nil) {

        NSString *key = [newUserPlaylistUrlRef key];

        NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"playlistId" : playlistId,
                                @"playlistName" : playlistName,
                                @"userDisplayName" : userDisplayName
                                };

        [newUserPlaylistUrlRef setValue:dict withCompletionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error, FIRDatabaseReference * _Nonnull ref) {

            NSLog(@"---- FirebaseManager::addShortUserPlaylistUrl completionBlock called - key: %@", key);

        }];
    }
}
```

Just tried on the simulator:

- the NSLog inside the block is not executed
- the setValue is done on the server as showed in the firebase console screenshot:

[image: firebase console]

The xcode console shows this:

```
2016-10-07 23:01:09.881 Metalplay PREPROD[45490:2301640] [FirebaseDatabase] Setting: /plr-playlist-url/plr-user-playlist-url/-KTW9VhscuqEfYYu1qh- with {
    playlistId = "-KTK5lFek22awzKaVCpU";
    playlistName = Toto;
    userDisplayName = eussam3;
} pri: <null>
2016-10-07 23:01:09.882 Metalplay PREPROD[45490:2301640] [FirebaseDatabase] Was connected, and added as index: 1
2016-10-07 23:01:09.882 Metalplay PREPROD[45490:2301640] [FirebaseDatabase] Sending: {
    d =     {
        a = p;
        b =         {
            d =             {
                playlistId = "-KTK5lFek22awzKaVCpU";
                playlistName = Toto;
                userDisplayName = eussam3;
            };
            p = "/plr-playlist-url/plr-user-playlist-url/-KTW9VhscuqEfYYu1qh-";
        };
        r = 12;
    };
    t = d;
}
2016-10-07 23:01:09.882 Metalplay PREPROD[45490:2301640] [FirebaseDatabase] (wsc:2) resetting keepalive, to 2016-10-07 22:01:54 +0000 ; old: 2016-10-07 22:01:40 +0000
2016-10-07 23:01:10.020 Metalplay PREPROD[45490:2301477] [FirebaseDatabase] (wsc:2) handleNewFrameCount: 1
2016-10-07 23:01:10.021 Metalplay PREPROD[45490:2301477] [FirebaseDatabase] (wsc:2) handleIncomingFrame sending complete frame: 0
2016-10-07 23:01:10.021 Metalplay PREPROD[45490:2301477] [FirebaseDatabase] Got data message: {
    b =     {
        d = "";
        s = ok;
    };
    r = 12;
}
```

Here is the version number used:

```
---------------------------------
MacBook-Pro-de-eussam:PLR eussam$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Firebase (3.4.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.3.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (3.0.4)
Using FirebaseDatabase (3.0.2)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.6)
Using GoogleAPIClientForREST (1.0.2)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.1)
Using GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.2.1)
Using GoogleParsingUtilities (1.1.1)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.1)
Using GoogleUtilities (1.3.1)
Using SDWebImage (3.8.1)
Using Toast (3.0)
Using youtube-ios-player-helper (0.1.6)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 7 dependencies from the Podfile and 15 total pods installed.
```

Comment: Can you include the code in completionBlock and how you verified it isn't reached? Also version info?

Comment: I would try upgrading to the latest SDK. I believe this may be addressed by "Fixed a race condition where performing a transaction or adding an event observer immediately after connecting to the Firebase Realtime Database service could cause completion blocks for other operations to not be executed." in 3.6.0 (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#3.6.0)

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer  very good point thanks, going to do a "pod update" since I'm using version 3.4.0 of firebase and did not think about updating for a while. will keep you posted tomorrow it's bed time in France :)

Comment: Upgrading from Firebase 3.4.0 to latest Firebase 3.7.1 seems to have sorted my problem out, completionBlock is called now all the time, device and simulator,  thank you very much for your time.