# FirebaseStorage Completion block not called. Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to simply load in a picture from firebase storage into my IOS app, but my completion block is not being called.

I use a TableViewController initially which loads plenty of pictures just fine. When I click on an item in the tableview it presents a simple view controller modally. I use the same code that successfully loads pictures in the TableViewController. **In this modally presented view controller, my FirebaseStorage completion blocks do not execute.** When I exit this view controller, the TableViewController can still load load pictures as necessary as I request.

I have enabled logging with `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`
and still do not receive any errors in my log.

I have allowed all read and writes temporarily in my rules for FirebaseStorage.

I have seen this question [iOS setValue withCompletionBlock not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923535/ios-setvalue-withcompletionblock-not-called) which states in the comments that a specific version of firebase had some issue with FirebaseDatabase blocking some other completion blocks.

The documentation said "Fixed a race condition where performing a transaction or adding an event observer immediately after connecting to the Firebase Realtime Database service could cause completion blocks for other operations to not be executed." from https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#3.6.0

In the above question the asker fixed the problem by upgrading to Firebase 3.7.1, I am using 5.0.1

Here are the versions I am using

```
Using Firebase (5.0.1)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.0.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (5.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (5.0.1)
Using FirebaseDatabase (5.0.0)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (3.0.0)
Using FirebaseStorage (3.0.0)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.15)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.4)
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Using nanopb (0.3.8)
Generating Pods project
```

I have logged all along my code to find that my code is being called, but the completion block is never executed. I am using the proper children ids, so I know that the storage reference does exist. I also know it is not a connection problem because the other pictures load fine just seconds before.

```
- (void)loadPicture {
    NSLog(@"Attempting to load picture");
    FIRStorageReference *ref = [[self.storageRef child:self.detailItem.faction] child:[self.detailItem firebaseEntry]];        
    [ref dataWithMaxSize:1024*1024 completion:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"Got a result!");
    }];
```

I am completely lost on what steps to take next. Has anyone experienced something similar or have any advice?

I appreciate any feedback that might help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Import this first

```
#import "UIImageView+FirebaseStorage.h"
```

and then for load image From reference use this

```
FIRStorageReference *gsReference = [[self.storageRef child:self.detailItem.faction] child:[self.detailItem firebaseEntry]];        

[yourImage sd_setImageWithStorageReference:gsReference placeholderImage:nil];
```

Comment: if you have any doubt regarding this code ask me i will help you

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by creating a new `ViewController` to do the same action from scratch. Unfortunately I don't know what the original problem was or how to reproduce it. My original `ViewController` was about as simple as possible. The problem seemed like a strange glitch/flaw in the API, xcode, or emulator since no errors were present and it fixed itself in the new `ViewController` using the same exact code.

Everything else I saw online pointed to a issue involving `Firebase 3.6.0` and below. Make sure you are using a recent `Firebase` version and then recreate the same ViewController and your problem will likely be fixed.